# Google maps API avoid translation of name

Tags: google-places-api, translation

I'm using the places api to search for places and quickly copy the some customer information into the front-end of my application.

But sometimes, the name gets translated to English, which is not desirable for the user. How can I avoid the translation of certain places?

For instance: **Krankenhaus Göttlicher Heiland** will be translated to: **Hospital of the Divine Savior**. It kinda sounds cool, but it's not what the user wants... :)

I know it takes default my browser settings and that you can add language on in the parameters, but I want to turn that off completely. So get the original native names.

Any idea?

Comment: I'm going to guess this is German (srry if is not). If you have your browser set to german do you still get addresses translated?

Comment: they were talking about this some years ago for directions API, https://buganizer.corp.google.com/issues/35819282

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply

Yes, it's the customer name is in German. 
But my tool is for global use and my UI is in English. 

However, my German users don't want their customer name to be translated to English

I can force the language parameter to 'language=de' (German) But that means the UI of google maps embedded in my application will also be in German, and that has to stay in English.

So basically I'm looking for a way to avoid translation and respect the original name. 

I also looked through the response object to see if the original name is somewhere there, but it's not :(

Comment: as far as i know this is the default for the API, to give places name in the native language, otherwise would be really hard for users to find places if everything is translated....check this out https://buganizer.corp.google.com/issues/35818032 the talk about a nl=1 (i guess is native language) for the geocode i don't know if supported for places.. I'll be looking into this

Comment: Yes, I understand, but native is not always the browser setting I guess. 
I'm in The Netherlands, but my browser setting is English and not Dutch. 
Dutch names get automatically translated to English, which sometimes looks very weird and funny. 

I would expect native name = the local name in country of origin, not country of user

Couldn't access buganizer though...

Comment: Gezellig! I am using places textsearch with a query=Krankenhaus Göttlicher Heiland and language=de and my browser is in English and I am getting formatted_address":"Dornbacher Str. 20-26, 1170 Wien, Österreich , name":"Krankenanstalt des Göttlichen Heilandes" in the respond

Comment: Yes, but how does your maps UI look like now?
Mine is in German, which is only useful for German users :)

Comment: the language parameter shouldn't change your UI language it only changes the language of the response you get. "The language code, indicating in which language the results should be returned, if possible. See the list of supported languages and their codes. Note that we often update supported languages so this list may not be exhaustive." as stated here https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/search

Comment: is there any other places in your code that you specified language? when you load the API ? in the script for example.

Comment: Yes, I looked at that list to see if there's like a 'global' language or something. 

There's no other place than the connection string to the API where I specify the language. I'm pretty much sure the parameter changes the UI as well. When I put it to Arabic, I get Arabic interface. 

my JS is based on the JS tutorial, 
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/tutorial
pretty straightforward

Comment: is it posible that you could pass a jsbin that recreates the issue so I can have it a look?

Comment: yes of course... 

Here you go
https://jsbin.com/vomakaqalu/edit?html,js,console,output

so changing the language parameter does change the UI

Comment: where are you doing the actual search? I just see the map and a button....and of course that the UI is going to change,  you are specifying the language in the script (as I suspected in one of my comments before)...I am afraid if you are only using the Javascript API there is no solution to this, if you want to control the language of the results in Autocomplete the only way is using the API WEB SERVICE ->  developers.google.com/places/web-service/search...good luck

Comment: I left out the code that didn't matter, since we were discussing the UI based on the language parameter. 

I extended the jsbin a bit, take a look: 
https://jsbin.com/weboraliyi/edit?html,js,console,output

So to conclude:  the name of the place might (doesn't always happen) automatically be translated to language parameter (or otherwise local browser setting) which also controls the UI language at the same time. There's no way to get the native name using this API, so the solution would be using the API web service?

Comment: yes, so inside your code you could do a GET request to the web API and there you specify the language, then only the results of the request is going to be translated

Comment: Great thanks for the work-around! :)